# How to return the letters of a word, instead of returning only a letter? Python

Tags: python, for-loop

So this one return the given letter.
I want it to return word. How to do it?
Thanks!

```
def print_big(letter):
    patterns = {1:'  *  ',2:' * * ',3:'*   *',4:'*****',5:'**** ',6:'   * ',7:' *   ',8:'*   * ',9:'*    '}
    alphabet = {'A':[1,2,4,3,3],'B':[5,3,5,3,5],'C':[4,9,9,9,4],'D':[5,3,3,3,5],'E':[4,9,4,9,4]}
    for pattern in alphabet[letter.upper()]:
        print(patterns[pattern])
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. For some input, what output do you expect? What does it currently give you? Why don't you understand the actual output?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
def print_big(word):
patterns = {1:'  *  ',2:' * * ',3:'*   *',4:'*****',5:'**** ',6:'   * ',7:' *   ',8:'*   * ',9:'*    '}
alphabet = {'A':[1,2,4,3,3],'B':[5,3,5,3,5],'C':[4,9,9,9,4],'D':[5,3,3,3,5],'E':[4,9,4,9,4]}
for letter in list(word):
  for pattern in alphabet[letter.upper()]:
    print(patterns[pattern])
    print("\n")
```

Comment: What purpose does `list(word)` serve?

Comment: @PeterWood Now I see actually it does nothing significant, is same without the list(). I always thought i need to use list() to get string in character list

Answer (score 0):

You need to join together each slice of output.

If we wanted to print CAB in large letters, the first slice would be `415`, and I assume extra spaces between `*****`,   `*` , and `****` :

`*****   *   ****`

I would rewrite your existing function to have a delegate function to get all the slices for a letter, without printing them:

```
def slices(letter):
    patterns = {1: '  *  ',
                2: ' * * ',
                3: '*   *',
                4: '*****',
                5: '**** ',
                6: '   * ',
                7: ' *   ',
                8: '*   * ',
                9: '*    '}
    alphabet = {'A': [1, 2, 4, 3, 3],
                'B': [5, 3, 5, 3, 5],
                'C': [4, 9, 9, 9, 4],
                'D': [5, 3, 3, 3, 5],
                'E': [4, 9, 4, 9, 4]}
    return [patterns[number] for number in alphabet[letter]]
```

Then we can use this to create a list of slices for a whole word:

```
def get_word_slices(word):
    return = [slices(letter) for letter in word]
```

Then we can print the slices by using [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and [**`str.join`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join each slice of each letter:

```
for slice in zip(*get_word_slices('CAB')):
    print(' '.join(slice))
```

`zip` takes a list of sequences, and then groups together the first item from each sequence, then the second etc. So, when we iterate over `zip` and say `print(' '.join(` it takes the first slices from each letter's slices, creates a single string, and prints it on one line of the screen, then the second, and so on.

The output is:

```
*****   *   **** 
*      * *  *   *
*     ***** **** 
*     *   * *   *
***** *   * ****
```